# Isomorphism between group presentations

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

Let
$$G_1=\langle a,b,c:\hspace{0.2cm}abc^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}c=1\rangle,$$
$$G_2=\langle d,e:\hspace{0.2cm}de d^{-1}e^{-1}=1\rangle.$$
How can I construct (if possible) a group isomorphism between $G_1$ and $G_2$?

I try to think of this as identifying the edges of a square and a hexagon both representing the torus, but I get stuck.

Thanks for the comments and help.

Comment: Why are you are asking for help with proving something that is not true? Doing that  wastes people's time.

Comment: @DerekHolt: The OP did not know if it was true or not. There are similar questions on MO and here which suggest that it is true. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978562/what-surface-do-we-get-by-joining-the-opposite-edges-of-a-hexagon

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128974/why-isnt-langle-x-y-zxyzx-1y-1z-1-rangle-a-hyperbolic-surface-grou

Answer (score 7):

These groups are not isomorphic because the abelianization of the first group is $\Bbb Z^3$ and the abelianization of the second group
is $\Bbb Z^2$. In fact the first group is the free product $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z^2=\langle b, ab, c^{-1}b\rangle$, where $(ab)$ commutes with $(c^{-1}b)$.